# Have subdomain act as root (htaccess?)

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website, with some content in the root folder.

I then have a Wordpress site in a subfolder of a subdomain. So for example the url to the Wordpress 'contact' page looks like this.

```
subdomain.mywebsite.com/subfolder/contact/
```

Is there a way to get this Wordpress site to act as the root of the website without moving files around? Either through an htaccess file or any other method?

It would be important that the user doesn't know they are in a subdomain/subfolder, so for the contact page of the wordpress site the url bar would have to look something like:

```
www.mywebsite.com/contact/
```

Would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in the vhost entry of your webserver.

Example main entry:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin xxx@xxx.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/Users/xxx/Documents/www/" 
    ServerName xxx.com
    ErrorLog "logs/xxx.error.log" 
    CustomLog "logs/xxx.access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Example subdomain entry:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin xxx@xxx.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/Users/xxx/Documents/www/subfolder" 
    ServerName subdomain.xxx.com
    ErrorLog "logs/subdomain.xxx.error.log" 
    CustomLog "logs/subdomain.xxx.access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by vhost entry? I'm looking at my website's cpanel and cant see anything named that. Should I be looking somewhere else?

Comment: Its a virtual host, normally you can just map a subdomain to a subfolder when using an adminstration panel, I don't exactly know cpanel though. Do you have access to the httpd.conf?

Comment: from what i've just read that's supposed to be in:
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf?

In my case there is no httpd folder in /etc/

Comment: As I said I dont know cpanel that well, but try to make the entry here:
Home »Service Configuration »Apache Configuration »Include Editor »post_virtualhost_global.conf, make sure to restart apache afterwards

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subfolder/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /subfolder/$1 [L]
```

This will internally map **/file/** to **/subfolder/file** if the requested file exists in /subfolder.

Comment: The problem is he only needs this if he comes from the subdomain

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. Does that take into account there being a subdomain?